# Laravel wrong password reset link

Tags: laravel, passwords, reset

I have come across this problem in `laravel` which I am not able to solve it for days. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

The password reset link is working properly on my localhost setup [example](http://localhost:8000/password/reset/d4f715ff43edda7357aed3af92f4f30afd2da65acaf45d18e8b9fcedba54ffcc)

However when I deploy it on to a production server the password reset [link](http://X.X.X.X/password/reset?5dbc352603fa617f8d465d4cdbfc4c5441ed2cc32b0e585dee1fa0a9ab95f0a5) that I got was different.

It seem to imply the quotation mark rather than the '/' which is supposedly to be the correct url. Anyone know what is the proper to go about fixing this wrong password reset link error?

Comment: How are you generating your URL code? and what does your route look like? There may be a mismatch between those things.

Comment: This is actually my route...Route::get('passwords/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.resetForm');

Comment: And how are you generating the actual URL on the blade template? Are you using the `route()` helper or something else?

Comment: This is the route that i used to send the email Route::post('passwords/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.sendEmail'); .......And on the blade frontend wise..i simply use the standard form action            
 <form method="POST" id="SendResetPassword" action="{{route('password.sendEmail')}}" class="col s12">
     {{csrf_field()}} </form> It does get send to my mail , however the reset url is wrong on the production server and not on localhost

Comment: What I suspect is happening is that there is a route conflict between some of your routes, such as `GET password/reset` and `GET password/reset/token` . If you are passing your token parameter like this `route('password.reset', $token)`  then it  might be trying to apply your token to the wrong route as a GET parameter instead as part of the URL itself (ie, /reset?{token} instead of reset/{token}). To confirm if this is the case or not, try changing your URLs into something different.

Comment: Wow thanks for the reply , it seem that there is really something wrong with my route , i will go figure it out , thanks for the helpful reply!

Comment: Glad I could help, I've encountered this issue before and it was frustrating for me at the time too. I'll make this an answer so that it might help others who have this problem too.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the help once again

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is happening is that there is a route conflict between some of your routes, such as GET password/reset and GET password/reset/token.

If you are passing your token parameter like this route('password.reset', $token) then it might be trying to apply your token to the wrong route as a GET parameter instead as part of the URL itself (ie, /reset?{token} instead of reset/{token}).

To confirm if this is the case or not, try changing your URLs into something different.

Comment: Sorry for the down vote , was a misclick on my part...kindly ignore it , thanks

Comment: indeed, i have solved mine because of route conflict